# Firebase auth move to continueUrl directly on email verification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently I am able to send an email verification from the client side using

`data.user.sendEmailVerification({
 url: "someurl"
})`

But this shows up a screen with "Continue" button like this:
[image]

I want to be able to skip this screen and directly let the user enter my site after email verification(because the template of this screen simply does not match my site's design and this screen seems clearly unnecessary to me).

Is that even possible and how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own email action custom landing pages by following this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).